# Added ellipsis for long text but it showing below the text

Tags: css

I used this css for ellipsis

```
.truncate {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[image]

I have given this css class to my `td` element and my text inside another span inside td

If you see dots coming below the text any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I think you gonna need to define the width or max-width, please post the HTML code.

Comment: Have you tried setting max-width for truncate class ?

Comment: @Pangloss Yes I tried with max width but no success. Sorry I can share the code because lots of code inside my html table.. Any other suggestion

Comment: Make sure it's a block or inline-block so the width applies, if it's in a table try adding table-layout: fixed;

Comment: We'll need to see the html to make an accurate diagnosis

Comment: Always you can extract the relevant parts of your code like css and html for that element ... https://jsfiddle.net/8mcdufoc/

Comment: max-width should work. https://jsfiddle.net/wietsedevries/e1qfd4y4/  Are there more css rules that we should know about?

Comment: Yes there are more css may be that casing the issue . I am not how to share my code with you guys. Let me try to create a jsfiddle with my issue if I can.. This is the other css https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/ I am using with angularJS.. I tried with   table-layout: fixed;

Comment: Yes found the issue. there is css class added in span with left:20px. that was causing the issue. I just changed that to margin-left:20px.. and solved

Comment: Didn't see you had a span inside your td, so .truncate needs to have a display type of 'inline-block' https://jsfiddle.net/wietsedevries/e1qfd4y4/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes found the issue. there is css class added in span with `left:20px`. that was causing the issue. I just changed that to `margin-left:20px`.. and solved

Answer (score 1):

For work text-overflow: ellipsis; the text should be in a container that has or it's inheriting some kind of declared width.